# Make the order of generic arguments redundant in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a middleware engine which is typed with various generic arguments that are relevant to the particular implementation when used.

```js
export type Middleware<

  Store = never,
  Args = unknown,
  Response = unknown

> = (

  context: {
    endpoint: string
    args: Args
    locals: {
      store?: Store,
      [key: string]: unknown
    }
  }

) => Promise<Response|void>|Response|void
```

The list of generic arguments are continuing to grow as I make the `Middleware` more feature-rich. Sometimes a `store` won't be present, where other arguments are. I know I can rely on defaults and parameter order, but (with many more arguments on their way) it's not the best developer experience having to list the arguments in the right order and provide `unknown` or `never` to the ones that come before others that need to be defined.

Is there a better way of providing arguments to generics that don't rely on the order, such that I may have any number of relevant generic arguments and the rest default to something defined in the most general case? Perhaps a map of some sort?

Comment: Nope. _JavaScript_ doesn't have named parameters, for that matter!

Comment: @jonrsharpe You can effectively have named parameters in JavaScript through the use of objects. So you can achieve the same thing. Is there no similar hack in TypeScript? Or any other tricks to reduce the need for passing redundant arguments in generics?

Comment: _Effectively_ but not, you know, _actually_.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to have a *generic* which uses many type arguments and some of them might or might not even be relevant. Doesn't sound very "generic" in that case. *Maybe* you can do something like accepting a single generic type parameter that is an option with the structure for `context`, however, perhaps it's better to rethink the approach.

Comment: Sometimes too generic function is not a good idea

Comment: @VLAZ I know what you mean; it feels a little cumbersome. Perhaps it's time to revisit the drawing board.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single type with properties on it:

```
type Get<T, K extends PropertyKey, TDefault> = 
    [T] extends [Record<K, infer U>] ? U: TDefault

export type Middleware<T extends {
  Store?: any,
  Args?: any,
  Response?: any
}> = MiddlewareInternal<Get<T, 'Store', never>, Get<T, 'Args', unknown>, Get<T, 'Response', unknown>>
export type MiddlewareInternal<

  Store = never,
  Args = unknown,
  Response = unknown

> = (

  context: {
    endpoint: string
    args: Args
    locals: {
      store: Store,
      [key: string]: unknown
    }
  }

) => Promise<Response|void>|Response|void
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=30&pln=30&pc=23#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwB4AqAaKBpKEAewIDsATAZygAUAnAe0gtHQhDSQBEIAzAQwFcAbYAHxQAvFABQUSVADaSALpZcBEjIBKEAMZUKhBOjQBLfOwgUoAVQEKA-BYBcUVhx78xYnGG3AooSFACyBoSEvBAA7pwUEMiKeESkAN4SUADKwNoQ1g6c+EzJAIIUAObEWVA5eZLqxJ74xJnZuWIAvkKigcGhEVEAkvh4FPicvAhwiKhQAORpGZNo+BAAbqYCaGPIaJOFJXNQ3PgA1vhUYfirsPAbU9W19bv7RydnAu7YnnQ+4NAdIeGREH0BkMRm5JDMoiIoAtlhQUAViqRRA9jqc4VUIDUqHVoEjDij8G42lAABSgqBafo4YAOJJSLBETxGalQYjAChGIrJSSREoObbELlQXhUDTDYg0wWSVkZBzgiBoukyA6MBys9n4IpyBzIp6C5rJfViACUIiElCoAFsDPUEDcsfUAD6LKhBAQOu3Yp0uwhuXzQAAakJ+XX+CCSrTEfqg-oATEGgr9utFaVI5TSoIthtxoA58NwLQAjUxQfURyNfaMAZnjnT+UTDgv5DmkecLpjQao5chaL19Ff9ABYa4nQynJE2ZK2i7CWWyu4KPfUoOnM7xs6q5xqSz2gA)

It's probably not 100% equivalent, but it might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for this; have upvoted as it does somewhat allow me to hide the complexity from implementation. But I think its' complexity hints to a point made in the comments about the lack of generic-ness in my original design. I'm having a rethink about how I structure my generics now.

Comment: @shennan I tend to agree that having a ton of generic parameters is a bad sign, so you might consider changing you design.